# IMPORTRANGE formula query to query data in another file

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Is it possible to create two different files where in the first I put the data and in the second the references query?

I used `IMPORTRANGE` but this method gives me "=CONTINUE(A1; 2; 1)"... I want to separate many sheets, to lighten the file, but also keep the references between them. In [this file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtZwzv4EAc54dDhxaFZxdHFwRUxXRnEwYmZ0ZHgyQ1E#gid=1) I have `foglio1` with the data while sum query is in the `foglio2` but I want to have this query in another (different) file.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very descriptive. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: sorry i wansn't too clear ..for example in this case i want to sum a1 and b1  but i whant to put the query in another file .. is it possible?

Comment: @jack1986 I have deleted your previous question. In future please *edit* your original question instead of re-posting. I suggest you take some time to read the [FAQ].

Comment: @jack1986: Please [edit] your question to clarify. Comments are impermanent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with a construct like so:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("key";"Foglio1!A2:B2")
```

and, in New Google sheets, allow permission for the linking. `key` above is the spreadsheet key (long upper/lower case alphanumeric between forward slashes visible in the URL for the source sheet). Though you can use the entire URL.